# nginx redirect HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: nginx, https, http-redirect

How can i redireect from https to http?

i have the code below but it does not seem to work.

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com$1 permanent;
 }
```

Comment: not without a SSL certificate. You need a server block with ssl certificate configuration and a redirect to the other non-ssl 80 server block. without a certificate HTTPS is not connectable, and a server that listens on 443 without ssl configurations is actually `http://domain:443` not the `https://domain/`

Answer (score 28):

The answer above will work, you need to generate a self signed cert (or have a real one) and configure nginx as such:

```
server {
  listen *:443;
  ssl on;
  server_name domain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent;

  ssl_certificate      /data/certs/domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /data/certs/domain.key; 
 }
```

Keep in mind, if it is a self signed cert the browser will give you an ugly warning.

Comment: Is it not possible to have this redirect without the ugly warning, without buying a certificate we won't use? Thanks!

Comment: You can get a free SSL cert from startssl, that'd get rid of the warnings.  self-signed certs will always throw the warnings you are talking about.

Comment: You can also replace ``rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent;`` with ``rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;`` if you have multiple server names specified.

Comment: What is the difference between ``listen *:443``, ``listen 443`` and ``listen 443 ssl``?

Comment: You can also get a free certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). I know I got late to the party...

Answer (score 16):

Building off jberger's comment a configuration that should work would be:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name example.com;
}

server {
    listen              *:443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Best yet, except the question is asking for https -> http .  Change the `https` to `http` and move the resulting `return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;` to the 443 server block.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ($host = 'foo.com') {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.foo.com$1  permanent;
    }
```

Comment: nginx [Pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name) and [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). This code should probably be refactored into two separte `server` blocks, one that catches http and another that catches https then does `return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;`.

Answer (score -5):

You need to create 2 separate server blocks:

1. Port 443 (HTTPS) - Define everything like PHP, 404, home, root etc in this block. Even if you want to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com or vice-versa, do it over here as @coulix has done.
2. Port 80 (HTTP) - In here you will just use:

```
server {
    listen    80;
    listen    [::]:80;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return    301    https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: the OP is asking to redirect HTTPS to HTTP not the other way around.