# How do I redirect HTTPS to HTTP on NGINX?

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirect, https

Is there a way to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP by adding a rule in the domain's vhost file?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Why is something like that useful? At first look I wasn't sure if it could be done. But it presented an interesting question.

You might try putting a redirect statement in your config file and restarting your server. Two possibilities might happen:

1. The server will issue the redirect - what you seem to want.
2. The server will first do the https exchange, and THEN issue the redirect, in which case, what's the point?

Will add more if I come up with something more concrete.

**UPDATE:** *(couple of hours later)*
You could try this. You need to put this in your **nginx.conf** file -

```
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name _ *;
       rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
 }
```

Sends a permanent redirect to the client. I am assuming you are using port 443 (default) for https.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _ *;
    ...
}
```

Add this so that your normal http requests on port 80 are undisturbed.

**UPDATE:** *18th Dec 2016*
- `server_name _` should be used instead of `server_name _ *` in nginx versions > 0.6.25 (thanks to @Luca Steeb)

Comment: Old answer but just want to say that it's useful because of the "insecure content" rule nowadays. When using an iframe for instance.

Comment: Another usage is when you are serving out a bunch of "discontinued" 404 pages for multiple domains via virtual hosts. There's no need to serve actual encrypted traffic, and it's not (easily) possible to put valid certs on each domain.

Comment: Another reason it would be useful: I have a server that hosts multiple domains. One of them has SSL, but the other domains don't have SSL certs. When someone goes to those other domains over HTTPS, it needs to redirect to HTTP

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still get problems when accessing my server:`OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: I think the solution is not right. redirect 443 to 80 without `ssl on`, doesn't match https, and it should not be worked. But if add `ssl on`, it will require ssl_certificates, and you must give the right certificate. so I think it can't  redirect https to http without certificate. related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470290/nginx-redirect-https-to-http

Comment: `server_name _` should be used instead of `server_name _ *` in nginx versions > 0.6.25

Comment: I don't think this is a right answer. You need a cert to meet ssl/https requirement, and then you can redirect to http/80 port. just as current 2nd popular answer is doing.

Comment: for static introduction websites or some api calls which doesn't need encryption

Answer (score 51):

`rewrite` and `if` should be avoided with Nginx.  The famous line is, "Nginx is not Apache": in other words, Nginx has better ways to handle URLs than rewriting.  `return` is still technically part of the rewrite module, but it doesn't carry the overhead of `rewrite`, and isn't as caveat-ridden as `if`.

Nginx has an entire page on [why `if` is "evil"](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).  It also provides a constructive page explaining [why `rewrite` and `if` are bad](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html), and how you can work around it.  Here's what the page has to say regarding `rewrite` and `if`:

> This is a wrong, cumbersome, and ineffective way.

You can solve this problem properly using `return`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    # You will need a wildcard certificate if you want to specify multiple
    # hostnames here.
    server_name domain.example www.domain.example;

    # If you have a certificate that is shared among several servers, you
    # can move these outside the `server` block.
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;

    # 301          indicates a permanent redirect.  If your redirect is
    #              temporary, you can change it to 302 or omit the number
    #              altogether.
    # $http_host   is the hostname and, if applicable, port--unlike $host,
    #              which will break on non-standard ports
    # $request_uri is the raw URI requested by the client, including any
    #              querystring
    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

If you expect a lot of bots that don't send a `Host` header, you can use `$host` instead of `$http_host` as long as you stick to ports 80 and 443.  Otherwise, you'll need to dynamically populate an `$http_host` substitute.  This code is efficient and safe as long as it appears in the root of `server` (rather than in a `location` block), despite using `if`.  However, you'd need to be using a default server for this to be applicable, which should be avoided with https.

```
set $request_host $server_name:$server_port;
if ($http_host) {
    set $request_host $http_host;
}
```

If you want to enforce SSL/TLS for specific paths, but forbid it otherwise:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.example;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;

    location / {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /secure/ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.example;

    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /secure/ {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

If your server isn't in direct communication with the client--for example, if you're using CloudFlare--things get a bit more complicated.  You'll need to ensure that any server in direct communication with the client adds an appropriate `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to the request.

Using this is a messy proposition; for a full explanation, see [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).  In order for this to be useful, the `if` block cannot be inside a `location` block, for a variety of complex reasons.  This forces the use of `rewrite` for URI testing.  **In short, if you have to use this on a production server... don't.  Think of it this way: if you've outgrown Apache, you've outgrown this solution.**

/secure, /secure/, and anything in /secure/ will enforce https, while all other URIs will enforce http.  The `(?!   )` PCRE construct is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  `(?:   )` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
server {
    # If you're using https between servers, you'll need to modify the listen
    # block and ensure that proper ssl_* statements are either present or
    # inherited.
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.example;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = https) {
        rewrite ^(?!/secure)/ http://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != https) {
        rewrite ^/secure(?:/|$) https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, there is no way to serve over http to a client that requests https without establishing an https connection first. So you need certs if you want to move people from https to http?

Comment: @Freek Right, although you should always support HTTPS; it's a pretty basic yet effective security feature, and any user who cares about their passwords will want it.  You can get a free certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).  Even if your website doesn't house any sensitive information, it could be used as an attack vector.

Comment: If you are behind an Elastic Load Balancer that 'removes the s' (https -> http), the only solution working is with if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = https)...

Comment: @jmcollin92 Ideally, you should be using HTTPS between ELB and Nginx.  That's what I tend to do.  It's less convenient but more secure.

Comment: I don't agree with that : double certificat installation => double reason to have to site down.

Comment: @jmcollin92 If security is of the utmost importance, it's worth the trouble.  It makes it more difficult for hacker with access to a server in your VPC to obtain useful information.  Hackers will often aim for old, forgotten servers, then work their way through the network.

Comment: Im looking for a way to do this for a dev server..  I wont be able to get a LetsEncrypt cert, nor do i want the extra time to setup an ssl connection just to drop it.   Is it technically impossible to return an http redirection address for an https request?

Comment: @Adeerlike Without a valid certificate, the client and server will never even be able to establish an HTTPS connection with each other, so you'll never get to the point at which you're able to return a response (such as a redirect).  You could use a self-signed certificate, but you'll need to add it to your browser or OS' trust store.  If it were possible to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP without a valid cert, that would constitute a major security vulnerability, and you'd likely be able to get quite a bounty payout if you were to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

```
location / {
    if ($scheme = https) {
        rewrite ^(.*)? http://$http_host$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: might need to add a location flag that is more encompassing than / if you want to ensure everything is matched.  But the answer with server is probably best to be honest.  How are you handling vhosts anyways?

Answer (score 6):

this question would have been better suited to the serverfault.com site.

A better way to do the redirect to http:

```
server {
   listen 443;
   return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This avoid both the 'if' clause and the regex in the rewrite that are features of the other solutions to date.  Both have performance implications, though in practice you'd have to have quite a lot of traffic before it would matter.

Depending on your setup, you are likely to also want to specify an ip in the listen clause, and perhaps a servername clause in the above.  As is, it will apply to all port 443 requests for all domain names.  You generally want an IP per domain with https, so mostly tying the above to an IP is more to the point than tying it to a domain name, but there's variations on that, eg where all domains are subdomains of one domain.

EDIT: TLS is close to universal now, and with it Server Name Identification (SNI) which allows for HTTPS sites on multiple domains sharing a single IP. There's a good write-up [here](https://serverfault.com/a/417580/134053)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name server.org www.server.org;
    rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the Nginx configuration file for your domain. This file is typically located in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory on Linux systems.
than inside your server block for the HTTPS(SSL) configuration, add the folowing lines to perform the redirection:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name your-domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/ssl/private-key.key;

    # Perform the HTTPS to HTTP redirect
    location / {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # Additional SSL configuration settings go here
    }
```

save and exit text editor than test your nginx config with :

`sudo nginx -t`

if temrinal showed "ok" and "valid" then you can reload nginx config using :

`sudo systemctl reload nginx`

This configuration will redirect all HTTPS requests to HTTP with a 301 (permanent) redirect

Answer (score -1):

The only simple rule is already explained on the post above me:

```
server {
    listen ip:443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
server{
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name mywebsite.com ;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

After inserting this code, all traffic for the HTTP default server redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: Question about redirect HTTPS to HTTP, not HTTP to HTTPS.