# Python socket server handle HTTPS request

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https

I wrote a socket server using Python 2.7 and the `socket` module.

Everything works as expected when I issue an HTTP request: the server accepts it and answers correctly. But if instead of (let's say) `http://a.com` I browse for `https://a.com` I receive some kind of encrypted header and I don't know how to tell the client that HTTPS is not supported by the server.

I googled a bit but nothing good. I tried to reply in plain HTTP but the response is clearly ignored by the browser.

If anyone would be able to show me a way to tell the client there's no SSL it would really help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In most cases there will be a webserver (nginx/apache/etc.) that can handle the SSL and proxy to your python app. Run a webserver and have python listen on a socket file or lock down requests to localhost only.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851034/opening-a-ssl-socket-connection-in-python and https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a way to have your connection be both ssl and non. In all cases I can think of you need separate ports, generally 80 (http), 443 (https)

Comment: Thanks Chris. But what if I _want_ to force the client to http? I know it's not secure and stuff, but just to know.

Comment: nginx can be configured to listen on both, and default to https, http://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http

Comment: Thanks Chris I really appreciate your help but I think we misunderstood. I'm not looking to establish an ssl connection, I would like to just say to the client "No boy, HTTPS here is not supported, use HTTP instead"

Comment: redirect port 443 traffic to port 80, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893839/how-do-i-redirect-https-requests-to-http-in-nginx

Comment: iptables won't let me redirect port 443 traffic anywhere else than 443

Comment: set "listen 443" and "ssl off"

Comment: Are you talking about the Pyhton socket or iptables? (Thanks Chris, you're very patient)

Comment: I was talking about in nginx (or whatever webserver you use). You could also tunnel the port with iptables, http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/ or in python you would probably need to run multiple threads to listen on 2 ports

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. You have to configure "ssl" context within your code as such:

```
import socket, ssl

HOST = "www.youtube.com"
PORT = 443

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOST)
s_sock.connect((HOST, 443))
s_sock.send(" GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.youtube.com\r\n\r\n ".encode())

while True:
    data = s_sock.recv(2048)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print(data)

s_sock.close()
```

Comment: The code above is for handling HTTPS from client side only. I believe server side HTTPS handling is done differently.

Comment: it produces error: OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Why is that so?

Comment: you create `context` but don't use it ?

Comment: Gives me this result:  b'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 54\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nDate: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 08:28:45 GMT\r\n\r\n<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>'

Comment: I also got `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`, and I found it was because there was a SPACE before `GET`.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596). The module names have changed so that they are now part of the `http.server` module (part of a standard installation) - see the note at the top of the [SimpleHTTPServer documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for Python 2. The main problem, though, is that you need to get an SSL certificate to secure connections with (the easiest way I believe is [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)).