# how would I establish an HTTPS connection in my browser, with browser requests redirected to proxy server

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, https, proxy

I've got here a simple python 3 code that listens on localhost:8080.

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
clientSocket.listen(1)

while True:

    try:
        (connection, address) = clientSocket.accept()
        browser_request = connection.recv(99999)
        print(browser_request.decode())

        serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serverSocket.settimeout(5)
        serverSocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1080))
        serverSocket.send(browser_request)

        response = serverSocket.recv(9999); 
        print(response.decode())

        connection.send(response)

    except Exception as e: print(e); pass
```

It gets the browser requests and redirects it on my proxy server which is listening on localhost:1080 (I use shadowsocksR proxy BTW)

"HTTP" connection works and sends data back on my browser.
But when it comes to https this happens

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Hll.jpg)

Comment: HTTPS may need certificate to encrypt connection.

Comment: @furas thanks I'll try searching that up

Comment: maybe this can help or shows you what to search: [Python socket server handle HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062925/python-socket-server-handle-https-request)