# Python GET request with sockets - 400 Bad request

Tags: python, sockets, http, https, http-status-code-400

I wrote this code to manually make a GET request using only python sockets. It worked perfectly fine back in 2016 when I wrote it but now I need it again and I keep getting the error code 400 bad request. I tried switching python version but it's still the same. I have been looking through Stackoverflow questions, asking more or less the same thing I do, but I just can't get it to work. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out. Here is my code, I removed all the IO and only posted the networking code.

```
URL_PATTERN = re.compile("^(.*://)?([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$")
HEADER_END = re.compile("\r\n\r\n")

URL_DATA = re.match(URL_PATTERN, INPUT_URL)
PROTOCOL = URL_DATA.groups()[0][:-3]
HOSTNAME = URL_DATA.groups()[1]
PATHNAME = URL_DATA.groups()[3] if URL_DATA.groups()[3] != "" else "/"
PORT = 80 if PROTOCOL == "http" else 443
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOSTNAME, PORT))

s.send("GET " + PATHNAME + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + HOSTNAME + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")

resp = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
HEADER_INDEX = re.search(HEADER_END, resp).start()
HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER = resp[:HEADER_INDEX]

s.close()
```

When I run my program on the URL https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/foreword.html

The variables from my program has the values:

**PORT**: 443

**PROTOCOL**: https

**HOSTNAME**: doc.rust-lang.org

**PATHNAME**: /book/2018-edition/foreword.html

And then I get the 400 bad request code back. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: To bring the answer of olin000 more to the point: the problem is that you are doing a plain HTTP request for a `https://` URL. Simply switching the port is not enough, you have to actually speak HTTP over TLS instead of plain HTTP. See the answer of olin000 for how you could implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's all about SSL. For reference you can check this question [Python socket server handle HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062925/python-socket-server-handle-https-request).

I suggest you use:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

and create a secure socket:

```
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOSTNAME)
s_sock.connect((HOSTNAME, PORT))
```

Additionally you might need to encode the message.

At the end your code could look like:

```
import re
import socket
import ssl

URL_PATTERN = re.compile("^(.*://)?([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)$")
HEADER_END = re.compile("\r\n\r\n")

INPUT_URL = "https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/foreword.html"

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

URL_DATA = re.match(URL_PATTERN, INPUT_URL)
PROTOCOL = URL_DATA.groups()[0][:-3]
HOSTNAME = URL_DATA.groups()[1]
PATHNAME = URL_DATA.groups()[3] if URL_DATA.groups()[3] != "" else "/"
PORT = 80 if PROTOCOL == "http" else 443
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOSTNAME)
s_sock.connect((HOSTNAME, PORT))

message = "GET " + PATHNAME + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + HOSTNAME + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
s_sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

resp = bytearray()
while True:
    part = s_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not part:
        break
    resp += part

s_sock.close()

resp_string = str(resp, 'utf-8')
HEADER_INDEX = re.search(HEADER_END, resp_string).start()
HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADER = resp_string[:HEADER_INDEX]
```