# Rewrite single page https to http Nginx

Tags: php, ssl, joomla, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite 'https://www.example.com' and 'https://example.com' to 'http://www.example.com' or 'http://example.com respectively'. I only want to write that specific part of the site not any subfolders or php related pages. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

I use it in the other direction (not tested in this direction but should work).

```
if ( $scheme = https )
{
  rewrite ^ http://$host$uri;
}
```

EDIT: limit to a location and end don't try to rewrite more:

```
location / {
  if ( $scheme = https )
  {
    rewrite ^ http://$host$uri last;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need it to only rewrite when people are at the url not any other pages. That directive rewrites the urls through the entire site.

Comment: This is so much the bad way of doing it ...

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls and http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: @Ownatik: from the page you cite:
"The only 100% safe things which may be done inside `if` in `location` context are:
`return ...;`
`rewrite ... last;` ". Here it's the second case, do you have better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've used something similar to the following, which avoid's [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and uses [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) instead of `rewrite` .  However it fails [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), which bothers me..  Suggestions welcome.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock ;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         .example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Rewrite only / to http
    location = / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock ;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

See also

- [nginx http location docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
- [related nginx https to http answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470290/nginx-redirect-https-to-http)