# Secure HTTP only REST API with HTTPS

Tags: rest, http, https

We have a supplier provided REST API that doesn't support HTTPS (only HTTP). Is there a way to secure the outbound REST PUTs (to AWS) using HTTPS? We were considering using STunnel  but this doesn't meet our internal InfoSec requirements. Would it be possible to put an IIS reverse proxy in and secure the outbound traffic from there?

Comment: I'm not sure why specifically IIS. Anyway I don't see any problem in putting a reverse proxy in front of AWS.

Comment: Apologies -  Should I be looking at URL rewrite rather than reverse proxy? As you can probably tell I'm not an IIS guy?

Comment: I don't know about IIS, but with nginx is a simple matter of rewriting `ssl on` to `http`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470290/nginx-redirect-https-to-http

Comment: if you have some sort of self hosted http app, and want to add some https magic, then you should look at nginx as common pattern for this case. If you have an external api provider, which support only http and you want to secure your requests - you have a big trouble, because i don't know any reliable possibility to do this